# Checkbox with Radio button type behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to replicate a radio button behaviour on a checkbox. What i am trying to do is at any given time atleast one checkbox should be check. So the scenarios is 
1) All checkboxes checked
2) first one checked
3) second one checked

but never both unchecked. i created a fiddle and trying to do it. if anyone can give insights it will be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc8.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3w8Z/76/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This plunker demonstrates solving this problem in angularJS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tHIGDmVljpHyA044xQTd?p=preview

The core of the solution involves this function which iterates the collection to ensure that at least one value is set to true.

```
this.testCollection = function(thingsList){
  return thingsList.some(function(thing){
    return thing.value === true;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with jQuery or with js logic is when you select one checkbox make other unselected

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N3w8Z/77/)

```
$(".sel").each(function()
{
    $(this).change(function()
    {
        $(".sel").prop('checked',false);
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
});


<div ng-app="app">
<div class="form-horizontal form-group">
    <label class="form-horizontal col-xs-3">Media:</label>
    <input class="form-horizontal col-xs-1 sel" name="grp" type="checkbox" ng-model="disablelist" ng-init="disablelist=true">
    <label class="form-horizontal col-xs-2">Play Music</label>
    <input class="form-horizontal col-xs-1 sel" name="grp" type="checkbox" ng-model="disableprofile">
    <label class="form-horizontal col-xs-3">Play Movie</label><br><br>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an Angular app, you could try this

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/f1p9h404/3/)

`function MyController($scope){
    $scope.changeFn = changeFn;
    function changeFn(){
        if(!$scope.disablelist && !$scope.disableprofile){
            $scope.disablelist = true;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This solution isn't scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I used some vanilla javascript to achieve the behavior you're after. Wrapped this code in a function, and hooked it to the onclick events for inputs. Added on to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6e2jzxbx/

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var oneActive = false;

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].checked == true){
        oneActive = true;
    }

    if(!oneActive){
        inputs[1].checked = true;
    }
}
```